# How to perform RMSE analysis in SPSS?

Tags: regression, spss, forecasting

My thesis coach wants me to perform a predictive analysis based on OLS. What I understand is the following:

- divide the dataset into a training set and a holdout set, for instance 50-50
- perform OLS on the training set
- construct linear equation based on regression output
- create a new variable (DV2) in the holdout set, and use the linear equation to 
  calculate its values
- now you have F (forecasted) and A (actual) DV values in the holdout set
- calculate the performance of the predictive linear equation with RMSE: 
  [image]
- a lower RMSE is better

Now, some questions about this procedure:

- Am I doing this right?
- I have no clue how to have SPSS perform the RSME operation, so can't I just do it in Excel? If I paste the holdout set into Excel, performing this calculation seems easy enough. Is there something I'm missing?
- If you know how to perform this calculation in SPSS, please let me know because I expect that SPSS might be able to output some extra insightful statistics and / or graphs

Answer (score 3):

Compute your random sample definition, e.g.,

```
compute part = rv.uniform(0,1) <= .5.
```

Run the regression.  Include this subcommand

```
/SELECT part EQ 1
```

and this

```
/SAVE PRED RESID
```

You can do this by specifying a selection variable in the Regression dialog box and by using the Save subdialog.

Now select the other part of the data, e.g.,

```
compute holdout = 1 - part.
```

Run Descriptives on `RES_1`.

Comment: I dont'quite understand this. I understand that by compuate part, you create a holdout and testset. I already got those. Then you perform OLS on the testset and save the residuals. But then I'm lost. You then just run descriptives on the residuals from the trainingset?